# How to shift foward actions using python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, nla-editor

I have two sequential actions, and I want to shift them both foward. 
I can list the actions with bpy.data.actons, but I don't know how to modify them.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can list the actions with `bpy.data.actions`, once they are in the *NLA Editor* you need to access them slightly differently.

Once in the *NLA Editor* they are classed as `strips` on `nla_tracks` which are stored in the `animation_data` for that object.

For example, in the case of the image you have shown you will use this to access an individual strip:

```
bpy.data.objects['sash_KIN_TYPE_S'].animation_data.nla_tracks['KIN_TYPE_SL'].strips['KIN_TYPE_SL_close']
```

From there you can access the `frame_start` and `frame_end` properties of the strip. Increasing both of these by the same amount will move the strip. For example:

```
strip.frame_start += 10
strip.frame_end += 10
```

To shift multiple strips you can loop over the `strips` collection in the same way you would loop over actions:

```
strips = bpy.data.objects['sash_KIN_TYPE_S'].animation_data.nla_tracks['KIN_TYPE_SL'].strips
for strip in strips:
    strip.frame_start += 10
    strip.frame_end += 10
```

I found all of this out by hovering my mouse over the properties in the *NLA Editor* and looking in the tooltip (because I enabled *Python Tooltips* in the *User Preferences*).